# Is there a trick to using phantomjs for javascript driven sites?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir, ghostdriver

Trying to use phantomjs to get content created by javascript and having a little trouble. Does phantomjs execute javascript just like other browsers do? Hoping someone can help.

When trying to get the value I'm looking for in Chrome, it comes up. However the value from phantomjs is blank.

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'watir'
 => true 
2.3.0 :002 > c = Watir::Browser.new
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x4598f2f5193003a8 url="data:," title=""> 
2.3.0 :003 > p = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
 => #<Watir::Browser:0x..fc337930306e55a98 url="about:blank" title=""> 
2.3.0 :004 > c.goto("http://www.walgreens.com/store/c/as-seen-on-tv/ID=359457-tier3")
 => "http://www.walgreens.com/store/c/as-seen-on-tv/ID=359457-tier3" 
2.3.0 :005 > p.goto(c.url)
 => "https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/as-seen-on-tv/ID=359457-tier3" 
2.3.0 :006 > c.element(:xpath => ".//*[@class='wag-itemscounttxt']/strong").text
 => "103" 
2.3.0 :007 > p.element(:xpath => ".//*[@class='wag-itemscounttxt']/strong").text
 => ""
```

As you can see the phantomjs value is not present.

Comment: p.element(:xpath => ".//*[@class='wag-itemscounttxt']/strong").inner_html did the job

Comment: This looks like a bug, you might want to report it.

Comment: Just run PhantomJS with these command-line options: `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --debug=true`